# Unsafe md5 How to get username and password for authentication using md5

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I am trying to store my password as md5. I just want to store this password using this because this is what i want in my application for login. Now, how can i get the username and password to authenticate in login. I don't know how to get the password because this md5 i know that it cannot be decrypted coz its not encryption. please help me how to do this.

this is my code:

```
public function storeUser($username, $password, $fname, $lname, $gender,  $address,  $contact, $age, $birthday) {
    //
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        //$hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        //$encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? md5($_REQUEST['password']) : NULL;
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO patient_user(unique_id, username, encrypted_password, fname, lname, gender, address,contact, age, birthday, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$username', '$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$gender','$address','$contact','$age','$birthday','$salt', NOW())");
        $result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(Id, username, password, salt) VALUES('$uid', '$username', '$password', '$salt')");
        /*$sql = "insert into users(Id, username, password, salt)
                                values ('".$uid."','".$username."', '".$encrypted_password."', '".$salt."')";   
        $result1 = $db->query($sql);
        */
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patient_user WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }


    /**
     * Get user by username and password
     */
    function getUserByusernameAndPassword($username, $password) {

       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patient_user WHERE username = '$username' and encrypted_password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());
        //$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
/*
       // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
           // $salt = $result['salt'];
            $password = $result['encrypted_password'];
           // $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
        */
    }
```

**EDIT**

I am using md5 because of this code below. This code is not my original work copied from site and just trying some modification. I really can't update the row of IP and port in the table users because the password being passed is different.

```
<?php
/****************************************
*       Server of Android IM Application
*
*       Author: ahmet oguz mermerkaya
*       Email: ahmetmermerkaya@hotmail.com
*       Editor: Dominik Pirngruber
*       Email: d.pirngruber@gmail.com
*       Date: Jun, 25, 2013     
*   
*       Supported actions: 
*           1.  authenticateUser
*               if user is authentiated return friend list
*           
*           2.  signUpUser
*       
*           3.  addNewFriend
*       
*           4.  responseOfFriendReqs
*
*           5.  testWebAPI
*************************************/


//TODO:  show error off

require_once("mysql.class.php");

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "healthhelp";


$db = new MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

// if operation is failed by unknown reason
define("FAILED", 0);

define("SUCCESSFUL", 1);
// when  signing up, if username is already taken, return this error
define("SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED", 2);  
// when add new friend request, if friend is not found, return this error 
define("ADD_NEW_USERNAME_NOT_FOUND", 2);

// TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS: if last authentication time of user is older 
// than NOW - TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS, then user is considered offline
define("TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS", 60);

define("USER_APPROVED", 1);
define("USER_UNAPPROVED", 0);


$username = (isset($_REQUEST['username']) && count($_REQUEST['username']) > 0) 
                            ? $_REQUEST['username'] 
                            : NULL;
$password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? md5($_REQUEST['password']) : NULL;
$port = isset($_REQUEST['port']) ? $_REQUEST['port'] : NULL;

$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : NULL;
if ($action == "testWebAPI")
{
    if ($db->testconnection()){
    echo SUCCESSFUL;
    exit;
    }else{
    echo FAILED;
    exit;
    }
}

if ($username == NULL || $password == NULL)  
{
    echo FAILED;
    exit;
}

$out = NULL;

error_log($action."\r\n", 3, "error.log");
switch($action) 
{

    case "authenticateUser":


        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
        {                   

            // providerId and requestId is Id of  a friend pair,
            // providerId is the Id of making first friend request
            // requestId is the Id of the friend approved the friend request made by providerId

            // fetching friends, 
            // left join expression is a bit different, 
            //      it is required to fetch the friend, not the users itself

            $sql = "select u.Id, u.username, (NOW()-u.authenticationTime) as authenticateTimeDifference, u.IP, 
                                        f.providerId, f.requestId, f.status, u.port 
                            from friends f
                            left join users u on 
                                        u.Id = if ( f.providerId = ".$userId.", f.requestId, f.providerId ) 
                            where (f.providerId = ".$userId." and f.status=".USER_APPROVED.")  or 
                                         f.requestId = ".$userId." ";

            //$sqlmessage = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";

            $sqlmessage = "SELECT m.id, m.fromuid, m.touid, m.sentdt, m.read, m.readdt, m.messagetext, u.username from messages m \n"
    . "left join users u on u.Id = m.fromuid WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";


            if ($result = $db->query($sql))         
            {
                    $out .= "<data>"; 
                    $out .= "<user userKey='".$userId."' />";
                    while ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                    {
                        $status = "offline";
                        if (((int)$row->status) == USER_UNAPPROVED)
                        {
                            $status = "unApproved";
                        }
                        else if (((int)$row->authenticateTimeDifference) < TIME_INTERVAL_FOR_USER_STATUS)
                        {
                            $status = "online";

                        }
                        $out .= "<friend  username = '".$row->username."'  status='".$status."' IP='".$row->IP."' userKey = '".$row->Id."'  port='".$row->port."'/>";

                                                // to increase security, we need to change userKey periodically and pay more attention
                                                // receiving message and sending message 

                    }
                        if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlmessage))           
                            {
                            while ($rowmessage = $db->fetchObject($resultmessage))
                                {
                                $out .= "<message  from='".$rowmessage->username."'  sendt='".$rowmessage->sentdt."' text='".$rowmessage->messagetext."' />";
                                $sqlendmsg = "UPDATE `messages` SET `read` = 1, `readdt` = '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."' WHERE `messages`.`id` = ".$rowmessage->id.";";
                                $db->query($sqlendmsg);
                                }
                            }
                    $out .= "</data>";
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
                // exit application if not authenticated user
                $out = FAILED;
        }



    break;

    case "signUpUser":
        if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
        {
             $email = $_REQUEST['email'];       

             $sql = "select Id from  users 
                            where username = '".$username."' limit 1";



             if ($result = $db->query($sql))
             {
                    if ($db->numRows($result) == 0) 
                    {
                            $sql = "insert into users(username, password, email)
                                values ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."') ";                          

                                error_log("$sql", 3 , "error_log");
                            if ($db->query($sql))   
                            {
                                    $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                            }               
                            else {
                                    $out = FAILED;
                            }                           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $out = SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED;
                    }
             }                      
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;

    case "sendMessage":
    if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)) 
        {   
        if (isset($_REQUEST['to']))
        {
             $tousername = $_REQUEST['to']; 
             $message = $_REQUEST['message'];   

             $sqlto = "select Id from  users where username = '".$tousername."' limit 1";



                    if ($resultto = $db->query($sqlto))         
                    {
                        while ($rowto = $db->fetchObject($resultto))
                        {
                            $uto = $rowto->Id;
                        }
                        $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`fromuid`, `touid`, `sentdt`, `messagetext`) VALUES ('".$userId."', '".$uto."', '".DATE("Y-m-d H:i")."', '".$message."');";                       

                                error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                            if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                            {
                                    $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                            }               
                            else {
                                    $out = FAILED;
                            }                       
                        $resultto = NULL;
                    }   

        $sqlto = NULL;
        }
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;

    case "addNewFriend":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
        if ($userId != NULL)
        {

            if (isset($_REQUEST['friendUserName']))         
            {               
                 $friendUserName = $_REQUEST['friendUserName'];

                 $sql = "select Id from users 
                                 where username='".$friendUserName."' 
                                 limit 1";
                 if ($result = $db->query($sql))
                 {
                        if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))
                        {
                             $requestId = $row->Id;

                             if ($row->Id != $userId)
                             {
                                     $sql = "insert into friends(providerId, requestId, status)
                                         values(".$userId.", ".$requestId.", ".USER_UNAPPROVED.")";

                                     if ($db->query($sql))
                                     {
                                            $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                            $out = FAILED;
                                     }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $out = FAILED;  // user add itself as a friend
                            }                                                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;                      
                        }
                 }                               
                 else
                 {
                        $out = FAILED;
                 }              
            }
            else
            {
                    $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;

    case "responseOfFriendReqs":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);
        if ($userId != NULL)
        {
            $sqlApprove = NULL;
            $sqlDiscard = NULL;
            if (isset($_REQUEST['approvedFriends']))
            {
                  $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['approvedFriends']);
                  $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                  $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                  for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                  {
                    if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                    {
                        if ($i > 0 )
                        {
                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                        }

                        $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";

                    }               

                  }
                  if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                  {
                    $sqlApprove = "update friends set status = ".USER_APPROVED."
                                    where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                ";      
                  }

            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['discardedFriends']))
            {
                    $friendNames = split(",", $_REQUEST['discardedFriends']);
                  $friendCount = count($friendNames);
                  $friendNamesQueryPart = NULL;
                  for ($i = 0; $i < $friendCount; $i++)
                  {
                    if (strlen($friendNames[$i]) > 0)
                    {
                        if ($i > 0 )
                        {
                            $friendNamesQueryPart .= ",";
                        }

                        $friendNamesQueryPart .= "'".$friendNames[$i]."'";

                    }                   
                  }
                  if ($friendNamesQueryPart != NULL)
                  {
                    $sqlDiscard = "delete from friends 
                                        where requestId = ".$userId." and 
                                                    providerId in (select Id from users where username in (".$friendNamesQueryPart."));
                                            ";
                  }                     
            }
            if (  ($sqlApprove != NULL ? $db->query($sqlApprove) : true) &&
                        ($sqlDiscard != NULL ? $db->query($sqlDiscard) : true) 
               )
            {
                $out = SUCCESSFUL;
            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }
    break;

    default:
        $out = FAILED;      
        break;  
}

echo $out;



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function authenticateUser($db, $username, $password)
{

    $sql22 = "select * from users 
                    where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."' 
                    limit 1";

    $out = NULL;
    if ($result22 = $db->query($sql22))
    {
        if ($row22 = $db->fetchObject($result22))
        {
                $out = $row22->Id;

                $sql22 = "update users set authenticationTime = NOW(), 
                                                                 IP = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."' ,
                                                                 port = 15145 
                                where Id = ".$row22->Id."
                                limit 1";

                $db->query($sql22);             


        }       
    }

    return $out;
}

?>
```

so i tried md5 also in my registration part instead of encryption and salt. so that when i authenticate the user and pass i don't need to decrypt it. I don't know. I'm really doing wrong here in this part.

Comment: *"How to get username and password for authentication using md5"* - **Why** should we contribute to a potential and next to inevitable hack? Don't use `md5`. It's old and dates back to 1996. A lot of water's gone under the bridge since. Use something like [`this`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) for instance. Not to mention using `mysql_ugh*`

Comment: Copy/pasting code from the internet that you don't understand seldom ends well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you trying to do:

```
 SELECT * FROM patient_user WHERE username = '$username' and encrypted_password = md5($password)
```

?

Comment: from function getUserByusernameAndPassword($username, $password) right? hmmm.. is that the only code i need to change there?

Comment: that should do it.  or set $encPass = md5($password) and put ...and encrypted_password = $encPass;

Comment: it's still not working. can u post an edit of whole program of what actually should i change?please?

Answer (score 2):

You know that MD5 can't be reversed. So what you will do is, every time the user type in a password to login, you will put the password in a new variable and process MD5 on that variable. Then you will compare that variable with the password on the database.